# Format jQuery date in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am passing jQuery date in backend. date is `Thu Jun 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)`.

I want to convert this date in `2017-06-19` this format but in php.

```
$date_str='Thu Jun 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)';
echo  date_format(date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $date_str), 'd-m-Y');
```

I have tried this solution but it is not working for me.

Comment: How do you want the solution? from php level or jquery level?

Comment: I want solution in php level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$timezoneDataStartPos = strpos($date_str," GMT");
$formattedString = substr($date_str, 0, $timezoneDataStartPos);
$formattedDate=DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s', $formattedString, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo $formattedDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

You need to remove `" GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)"` and make sure to preserve Timezone as `Asia/Kolkata`

Comment: if user using from other country then there is no `GMT0530` then there is some other timezone

Comment: Edited the code, now it should work :) @chirag-satapara

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Note : Remove `0530 (India Standard Time)` from your date format and use date format shown below my code.

```
<?php
$date_str='Thu Jun 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT ';
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_str));
?>
```